# Calling Command Prompt and executing a command through Shell Exec in VBA

Tags: vba, vbscript, command-prompt, wsh, windows-scripting

I'm trying to execute a command on command prompt using Shell Script in VBA Excel. When I execute this command on command prompt it works by printing a number as output. But when I call the same command in the script it doesn't show this number in the message box.

```vb
Sub Button6_Click()
    Dim oShell As Object
    Dim objExecObject As Object
    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set objExecObject = oShell.Exec("cmd /c convert test2.jpg -fill black +opaque white -fill white -opaque white -print %[fx:w*h*mean]")
    MsgBox (objExecObject.StdOut.ReadAll)
End Sub
```

I think the problem is with the arguments in the `Exec` function as there are multiple words. So I tried the following by concatenating a string as shown. But this doesn't work either.

```
    Dim command As String
    command = "convert test2.jpg -fill black +opaque white -fill white -opaque white -print %[fx:w*h*mean] null:"
    Set objExecObject = oShell.Exec("cmd /c " & command)
```

There seems to be no runtime error and the message box always returns empty without printing the number. To clarify: the `convert` command is a function provided by ImageMagick.

Please tell me how I can run the convert command in command prompt and print the output of command prompt in the message box.

Comment: This worked. 
Set objExecObject = oShell.Exec("cmd /c convert test2.jpg -fill black +opaque white -fill white -opaque white -print %[fx:w*h*mean] null:")
The null at the end of the command was the problem. Also make sure that the path of the file is absolute which in my case was not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When a command 'works' from a console but 'fails' when .Exec'ed, the usual suspects are

1. pathes -> use quoted full/absolute file specs for executables and data files
2. permissions -> check user(s)/rights
3. console runs a shell vs .Exec starts a process

In your case the meaning of 'works/fails' isn't entirely clear. The symptom is "MsgBox does not show a number". Perhaps convert writes to StdErr. So try:

```
MsgBox objExecObject.StdErr.ReadAll()
```

or - better -

```
If Not objExecObject.StdErr.AtEndOfStream Then MsgBox objExecObject.StdErr.ReadAll()
```

If that does not help, use .Run() with "%comspec% /k".

**Update wrt comment:**

Start convert from a console and re-direct its output to a file for further checking.

Comment: 1,2,3 are not the problem. Both your codes haven't worked. When I use Run then the command works on cmd but I need the output(number in this case) so that I can write this on excel cell. With run I won't be able to do this.